# How to count all the rows of a table from a query with some filters who has a limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, mariadb

I will try to be more specific, let's suppose that i have this query:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 LIMIT 5;`

In my table `users` i have 40 users who has the status = 5, but in my query i'm limiting to 5, and that's fine, that's what i want to do.

But now, i need to count all users (without limit) who has the status = 1, in this case, 40 users has that status.

How can i do that without make another query?

I don't want to make other query 'cause in the query that i'm really working i have more filters, and i think that make double query with the same filters (except for the limit) is spent innecesary resources from my server.

Also i don't want to remove the `LIMIT 5` from my query and take 5 in the code 'cause i have too many users with that status, and get all those users just for count it is innecesary,
I think there must be a better way to do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of MariaDB or MySQL 8+, then you may use `COUNT` as a window function here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
    FROM users
    WHERE status = 1
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY some_column
LIMIT 5;
```

Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because in that case you are not telling the database *which* five records you want.  Add an `ORDER BY` clause for best results.